# Select missing rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm currently building a multilingual website, where content is added in English first and than translated into other languages.

All the content is stored in one MySQL table that looks like this:

```
id | language | title               | master
1  | en       | Page one title      | 1
2  | es       | Página un título    | 1
3  | de       | Seite einen titel   | 1
4  | en       | Page two title      | 2
5  | es       | Página dos título   | 2
```

What I need to do is be able to get a list of all the content that still needs to be translated. In the case above it would be #4 needs to be translated into German.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: How many other languages are we talking about? Is there a list of all languages somewhere in the database?

Comment: It may be a good idea to put the languages in a table of their own.  That master column looks like it could use a similar treatment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select master
from MyTable
group by master
having count(distinct language) < 3
```

Comment: Nice inference! Your answer made the post sensible

Answer (score 2):

If you want not only the count, but also the info what is missing you migh want to try

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(language ORDER BY language) as languages_done
FROM tablename
GROUP BY master
HAVING languages_done<>'de,en,es'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use this to find the content and the translations still needed.

```
SELECT    master
          , Languages.language
FROM      MyTable
          LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT    DISTINCT language
              FROM      master
          ) AS Languages
              ON  master.language = Languages.language
WHERE     master.language IS NULL
```

Hope this helps,

Pete

Comment: +1, but instead of @Languages I would use `(select distinct language from MyTable)` - it can grows dynamically with main table :-).

Answer (score 0):

- Find all the languages in use.
- Find all the master documents in use.
- Create a list of all master documents in all languages.
- Remove the list of documents already translated (MINUS or EXCEPT depending on platform)

  ```
  WITH languages AS (SELECT DISTINCT language FROM mytable),
       masters AS (SELECT DISTINCT master FROM mytable)
  SELECT m.master, l.language
    FROM masters m, languages l
  MINUS
  SELECT m.master, m.language
    FROM mytable m
  ```